# MySQL Workbench Model sync sql_mode

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Using MySQL Work Bench, When I look at the system variables of a server I am connected to, it shows the SQL_MODE as "no engine substitution"

When I open a Workbench Model, and use the "sync with any source" menu item. When it alters the tables, it runs the alter query using the follow sql_mode:

```
SQL_MODE='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

Im not sure where it is getting that from, is it safe to override the sql_mode in the connection  to be just no engine substitute?

Why would it be trying to use a different mode when altering than the server shows it is using?

The server itself is running 5.6.47

Answer (score 0):

MySQL takes his configuration from the my.cnf/ini file where you can activate or disable the modes or options.

There is also the possibility to put options to the program when it starts.

Please read up on the sql Modes or configuration that you want to change, but remember  the defaults are there for a cause, but the Mysql homepage has usual a  lot to tell about [see](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html), but read the **warnings** carefully. Everything could end in disaster.

I alos din't know where you see t taht the sql is empty, i am guessing that you mean https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-preferences-general-editors.html

Bujt that is as you can see something different